# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (cordova)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, indexing, scripting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyt5N.png)

i dont know what happens but the ionic cant load the cordova and cordova in print was written in the code,how ca i fix it

Comment: Can you provide more insight please? what are you trying to load? was it working at any point?
If you are trying to "load" cordova, CDN in Index.html is not the way.
Are you familiar with npm?

Comment: @Haythem yes i alredy use npm ,my project is use an gps for moblie using ionic, so i already change the css and do the design of project , call the geolocation and google map in home.page.ts and do some function in, i already have the api key bye the google services and its my first time using stack overflow so i cant explain :/

Comment: How about you start with sharing a screenshot of the problem maybe? also providing the code where you are facing problems may help.
Also [Here's how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i already post a screenshot of the problem showing in the command and put some code

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIJBE.png)

my home page ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, LatLng } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import{Platform,NavController} from '@ionic/angular'


declare var google:any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'], 
})
export class HomePage {
  map : any;
  markers: any;
  

  estabelecimentos = [{
nome:'estabelicimentos1',
lat:41.5518 ,
lng:-8.4229
},{
  nome:'estabelicimentos2',
  lat: 41.3301,
  lng:-8.2512

  }]
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public geolocation: Geolocation, private platform:Platform) {}

  IonViewWillEnter(){
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      this.initPage();

    })
  }

  initPage(){
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then( result =>{
      this.loadMap(result.coords.latitude,result.coords.longitude );
    })
  }

  loadMap(lat,lng){
    let LatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)

    let mapOptions={
      center: LatLng,
      zoom:14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      DisableDefaultUI: true
    }
    let element=document.getElementById('map');
    this.map=new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions)
  }
}
```

my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import{HomePageModule} from './home/home.module';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,HomePageModule],
  providers: [ Geolocation,{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my home.page.html

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">

  <div id="map">
    <body>
      <div class="button_camera">
        <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="button_home">
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="button_search">
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="top-image"></div>
      <div class="button_zoom_in">
        <ion-icon name="contract"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="dot1"></div>
      <div class="dot2"></div>
      <div class="dot3"></div>
      <div class="button_zoom_out">
        <ion-icon name="expand"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </body>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

ok i think thats enough , if u need more something tell me , know i know how to work in stackoverflow thank you